# How to display icon/image after selecting an option from dropdown list in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to display an icon/image after selecting something from my dropdown list. It works when my file is in .html format but it somehow doesn't when I am working with Vue and I don't know why? I created a recipe form, where you can submit your input (recipe name, description ...), which will be displayed on a final recipe card.

```
<img id="imageToSwap" src="" />
                      
  <select class="form-control" id="dlist" name="dlist" onChange="swapImage()">
    <option value="..\assets\images\meat.jpeg"> meat </option>
    <option value="..\assets\images\veg.jpeg"> vegetarian </option>
    <option value="..\assets\images\vegan.jpeg"> Vegan </option>
  </select>
```

```
<script>

export default {
  methods: {
    swapImage(){
      var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
      var dropd = document.getElementById("dlist");
      image.src = dropd.value;  
    }
  }
};
```

The output is not the picture or what I wrote between the  tags but instead it only displays the path (example: "..\assets\images\meat.jpeg"). So I guess the problem could be "value" of . Does somebody know an alternative or could help me out? Thanks in advance.